# Testing group means = 0 for multiple factors

Tags: r, mixed-model, post-hoc

I have a dataset that I am analyzing in R.  In this data set a value of 0 is meaningful.  Therefore, I would like to compare each group mean to 0 rather than comparing them to each other as is typically done.  The data has two factors (3 levels and 11 levels, but for the sake of brevity we can consider both to have 3 levels), a covariate (continuous), and a random variable (factor with 5 levels).

fit <- lme(value ~ factorA + factorB + covariate, dat, random= ~ 1|randomVar)

tuk <- glht(fit,linfct = mcp(factorA = "Tukey"))

With this code I get all of the comparisons of the different levels of factorA to each other.  I want comparisons of each level of factorA and each level of factorB to zero, and importantly that needs to include the reference levels of both factors.  I know that I need to set up the contrasts different, but I don't know how.

Edit: I tried to set the contrasts manually with e.g c(1,0,0,...) for factorA_level1 and c(1,1,0,...) for factorA_level2 but it appears to not give the overall group means but rather the group means for the reference level of factorB or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way with the `emmeans` package:

```
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(nlme)

dat <- iris
dat$factor <- as.factor(rep(1:3,50))

fit <- lme(Sepal.Length ~ factor + Sepal.Width, dat, random = ~ 1 | Species)

mm <- emmeans(fit, ~factor)
mm # individual confidence intervals
# factor emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# 1        5.87 0.59  2     3.33     8.41
# 2        5.77 0.59  2     3.23     8.31
# 3        5.89 0.59  2     3.35     8.43
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: containment 
# Confidence level used: 0.95 

# simultaneous tests and confidence intervals ####
mult <- as.glht(mm)
summary(mult)
# Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
# 
# Linear Hypotheses:
#          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#   1 == 0   5.8692     0.5898   9.951   0.0115 *
#   2 == 0   5.7689     0.5899   9.780   0.0120 *
#   3 == 0   5.8920     0.5899   9.989   0.0113 *
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

confint(mult) 
# Simultaneous Confidence Intervals
# 
# 95% family-wise confidence level
# 
# Linear Hypotheses:
#        Estimate lwr    upr   
# 1 == 0 5.8692   3.1193 8.6190
# 2 == 0 5.7689   3.0189 8.5189
# 3 == 0 5.8920   3.1420 8.6419
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I am going to try this out as soon as possible. I will let you know how it works

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. It worked perfectly, thank you. I have accepted this answer.

Comment: You can also do this in fewer steps: `test(mm, null = 0, `adjust = “mvt")`